# Kronecker's famous quote about integer numbers

Tags: math-history

I am working with the excellent book of Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*.
The author (p. 3) quotes Kronecker:

> The natural numbers are the work of God. All the rest is the work of the mankind.

As far as I know the exact quote attributed to Kronecker reads:

> God made the integers; all else is the work of man.

[Die ganzen Zahlen hat der liebe Gott gemacht, alles andere ist Menschenwerk

In German ganzen Zahlen stands for integer numbers;  natürlichen Zahlen means natural number]

Is it this just a simple misquote of the author or am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you would do better to ask this question (which is essentially about German mathematical terminology in the 19th century) on https://hsm.stackexchange.com. (As an uninformed conjecture on my part, I would imagine that Kronecker would have considered negative numbers to be Menschenwerk. So my guess would be that his ganzen Zahlen did not include negative numbers. As for $0$, I wouldn't care to guess.)

Comment: I suggest not so much misquote as paraphrase, to fit a particular modern English math book's  likely readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a free preview. In context, the author does not think the reader yet knows what the word *integers* means. The quote is paraphrased, very much on purpose.

[image]